# Required nullable property still validates when property is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-core, nullable

I've got a basic model like so:

```
public class MyModel
{
  [Required] public int? Id { get; set; }
  [Required] public string Name { get; set; }
  [Required] public Guid? BigId { get; set; }
}
```

And a controller which accepts these properties from the path:

```
[HttpPost("api/{bigId}/blah/{name}/{id}")]
public IActionResult Post([FromRoute] MyModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return BadRequest(ModelState);

  // ...
}
```

I POSTed to the following url: http://localhost/api/%20/blah/%20/%20

My controller receives a model containing all null properties, yet `ModelState.IsValid` returns true. Why would that be?

Comment: However, if I POST to http://localhost/api/a/blah/b/c, then I get model validation errors for the bigId and the Id (which makes sense).

Comment: Can the `IsValid` method be added to the question?

Comment: It's a built-in property of controller classes

Comment: Is the `IsValid` overridden?

Comment: Nope, can't override properties anyway

Comment: Is all elements being null technically a valid state?

Comment: Not according to the rules of the Required attribute

Comment: According to docs, `[Required]` attribute means "The RequiredAttribute attribute specifies that when a field on a form is validated, the field must contain a value. A validation exception is raised if the property is null, contains an empty string (""), or contains only white-space characters." which contradicts what the OP is observing